# How to use gRPC with Kotlin Ktor

Tags: kotlin, netty, grpc, ktor

Where can I find examples of using gRPC with ktor. Is it possible, has anyone done such before? I need help.

I have tried following this sample: https://github.com/renannprado/ktor-grpc-sample but I could not get it to work and the sample may not be complete.

Comment: Posted the question to the Ktor team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1501. Please vote for the issue there to get it on the roadmap.

Comment: Nothing yet on this, looks like the Ktor team is working on something, more info here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1501